# "Unexpected reserved word You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type." using Webpack in Reapp

Tags: javascript, requirejs, reactjs, require

I'm trying to import some Javascript code into a [Reapp](http://reapp.io/) project. But I've this error when I run `reapp run`.

> Module parse failed: Line 8: Unexpected reserved word You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type. | var SearchPageStore =
>   require('../../../../Core/Modules/SearchPage/Store/SearchPageStore');

It looks like this is the using of the `require` function that causes this error. However, I can't modify this code because it's reused by several other Javascript applications.

Any suggestion on how fix this error message?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide with your webpack.config.js and package.json, so that more information is there to dig deeper